Execution failed for task ':expo:compileDebugKotlin'
Issue
I’m encountering a build error when running my React Native project. The error message is:
Execution failed for task ':expo:compileDebugKotlin'.

A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
Compilation error. See log for more details

Build Configuration
Here’s the relevant section of my build.gradle file:
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "+"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 33 =>34
        targetSdkVersion = 33=>34
        kotlin_version = '1.9.0' newly added

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == 'aarch64') {
            ndkVersion = '24.0.8215888'
        } else if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            ndkVersion = '23.1.7779620'
        } else {
            ndkVersion = '21.4.7075529'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
        classpath('de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2')
        classpath('org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.1')
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15')
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
    }
}

Dependencies
Here’s a snippet of my package.json dependencies:
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.5.1",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.3.1",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^20.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.8",
    "expo":  45.0.8 => "^46.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.14.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.6.3"
}


keeping the expo at ^45.0.8 doesn't change the issue.
